# Does joblib's memoization support being called from multiple tasks?

Tags: scikit-learn

if a function that is being memoized called in parallel from two jobs, what happens? One call's result is saved and other is retrieved or both run without using each other results? Or this case is not supported at all?

Couldn't find a reference to this in the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a result has already been computed and saved (by the same process or by a concurrent process) it is reused.

If 2 concurrent processes compute the same result for the first time, the first process to complete saves the result on the drive for later reuse and the second process use its own computation result the first time and later can reuse the cached result.

Also the cache is preserved on the hard drive after a Python program ends so that it can be reused when the same script / program is restarted later.

Comment: Great, thanks. BTW what's the best way to clear all cache? iterate over all functions and issue 'clear' per func or just delete the cache directory and recreate it?

Comment: You can delete the directory, joblib will re-create it itself if needed.